# Cannot boot Qubes after successful installation

Tags: linux, partitioning, unix, uefi, qubes-os

There is a problem with booting Qubes 4.1.1 after installation marked by installer as successful. The validity of the image is confirmed and hardware requirements should be passed.

**SETUP** [[docs]](https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/system-requirements/)

- Intel Core i9-10900K
- MSI MPG Z490 GAMING EDGE WIFI
- Corsair MP400 2TB
- NVIDIA GeForce 1060 6GB

**PROCEDURE**

1. Reset UEFI to default values: `Settings - Save & Exit - Restore Defaults`
2. Disable Secure Boot: `Settings - Security - Secure Boot - Secure Boot`
3. Enable VT-x(d): `OC - CPU Features - Intel Virtualization Tech, Intel VT-D Tech`
4. Set SATA mode to AHCI: `Settings - Advanced - Integrated Peripherals - SATA Mode`
5. Set NVMe as first in boot priority: `Settings - Boot - FIXED BOOT ORDER`
6. Install Qubes using ‘Test media and install Qubes OS R4.1.1’

**OUTCOME**

Installation ends with saying the operation was successful and that user is ready to use Qubes. Not sure if relevant but getting this after clicking Reboot button:
[image]

PC doesn't reboot means there is a need to power the computer off and manually start it again, removing the installation USB stick meanwhile. PC boots into UEFI.

**TROUBLESHOOTING PASSED**

**Boot device not recognized after installing** [[docs]](https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/uefi-troubleshooting/#boot-device-not-recognized-after-installing)

Tried to execute command:

`cp -r /boot/efi/EFI/qubes/. /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT`

Output:

`cp: cannot stat '/boot/efi/EFI/qubes/.': No such file or directory`

Checking up the `boot` directory:

`cd boot`

`ls`

Output:

`initramfs-5.15.52-1.fc32.qubes.x86_64.img`

**Accessing installer Rescue mode on UEFI** [[docs]](https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/uefi-troubleshooting/#accessing-installer-rescue-mode-on-uefi)

`pkill -9 anaconda`

`anaconda --rescue`

`> 1`

`> {PASSPHRASE}`

`You don't have any Linux partitions. Rebooting.`

`Please press ENTER to get a shell:`

Checking up on partitions:

`fdisk -l`

[image]

What’s the catch? Thank you so much for the help.

**EDIT #1**

- Tried to install Qubes without GPU attached - didn't help
- Tried switching from `UEFI` mode to `CSM` - didn't help

**EDIT #2**

- Looks like installer runs in correct mode (EFI). See output of `ls /sys/firmware/efi`: `config_table efivars fw_platform_size systab`

**EDIT #3**

- There is probably problem with mounting a partition. When I `lsblk` in shell I got these results:

[image]

None of the NVMe has its mount point set. I went to Mint (Debian based) shell and executed this script:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

mount -v /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/ && cd /mnt/
mount -v /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/efi/

apt install -y efibootmgr

efibootmgr -v 

echo '# EFIbootmgr fix start'
efibootmgr -v -c -u -L QubesOS -l /EFI/qubes/grubx64.efi -d /dev/nvme0n1 -p 1 && echo "# EFIbootmgr fix done"
#efibootmgr -v 

cd /; sleep 1
umount -v /mnt/efi
umount -v /mnt
```

After reboot Qubes doesn't boot (still the same problem). When I plug in Qubes USB stick and go to shell I got the same `lsblk` results. What could cause this problem with no mounting?

Comment: It appears a bootloader was not installed. I’m not familiar with Qubes so I don’t know what went wrong.

Comment: @DanielB What exactly led you to this conclusion?

Comment: You mention enabling VT-d, is it safe to assume that VT-x is also enabled?

Comment: @xentoo Yes, I have added that info to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @xentoo and other helpful folks Qubes was booted. However the cause of the problem haven't been confirmed. There are two options in play: NVMe or UEFI. Find procedure down below that made Qubes boot (tried multiple times):

PROCEDURE

*Values for MSI MPG Z490 GAMING EDGE WIFI*

1. Reset to default values
2. Set `Advanced - BIOS CSM/UEFI Mode` option to `CSM`
3. Set `Advanced - Intergrated Peripherals` option to `AHCI Mode`
4. Set `Overclocking - CPU Features - Intel VT-D Tech` option to `Enabled`
5. Set the disk as first in boot priorities menu
6. Save and reboot
7. Apply `Advanced - Secure Erase+` to the disk
8. Plug USB stick with Qubes installation
9. Install using `Test media and install Qubes OS R4.1.1`

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the installation process was not successful, as the `/boot/efi/` directory hasn't been populated correctly.

In this scenario, it would be worth running through the install process again. Making sure that `VT-x` & `VT-d` are enabled, `UEFI mode` enabled, `CSM` disabled and check the NVMe settings are correct. Be sure to set the NVMe boot priority.

When going through the motions with anaconda, use manual partitioning and make sure the partitions are created properly. If everything goes well, you should be able to reboot into UEFI and make sure the new EFI partition shows up as a boot option. Set it to the first boot option if it hasn't done so already.

At this point you should be able to boot into your new qubes install.

Comment: I have confirmed the needed settings. Could you provide info about how should partitions look like? If I set it to automatic I get: /boot/efi nvme0n1p1, /boot nvme0n1p2, / qubes_dom0-root, swap qubes_dom0-swap and ext4 qubes_dom0-vm-pool which has no mount point! Could that be the problem? Where should I mount it?

Comment: Those partitions appear to be absolutely fine from the automatic partition scheme. Was the installer definitely in efi mode and not in bios? As it is probable that the qubes installer ran in legacy mode. If you run the installer again, when anaconda loads open the terminal and run ```ls /sys/firmware/efi/``` if the ls output is populated with ```efivars```, ```systab```... etc ... then the installer is in efi mode. If the output is ```No such file or directory``` then it is in legacy mode.

Comment: I got `config_table`, `efivars`, `fw_platform_size` and `systab` - assuming installer is in EFI mode. Since UEFI mode is set to `UEFI` and NOT `CSM` I guess the installer runs in correct mode. Any idea where should I direct the investigation next?

Comment: If you boot from another live USB, are you able to mount the EFI partition?

Comment: I have tried this, please refer to "Edit 3" in my question.